# PineScript error never seen ~ The body of the #f0 function is too long

Tags: pine-script

As the title says it, I have never seen this type of error whereas not even a line number is given only "The body of the #f0 function is too long"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is relevant regarding functions, but this is information relating to errors thrown due to lengths of 'if' statements, I presume the same logic here is valid with functions too.

"This error occurs when the indented code inside an if statement is too large for the compiler. Because of how the compiler works, you won’t receive a message telling you exactly how many lines of code you are over the limit. The only solution now is to break up your if statement into smaller parts (functions or smaller if statements)."

So, I would suggest you break the function into sections (if possible) or post some code so we may be more able to assist.